# Error with WMTS displayed in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wmts

Here is a part of my `js` code :

```
const resolutions = []
const matrixIds = []
const proj3857 = getProjection("EPSG:3857")
const maxResolution = getWidth(proj3857.getExtent()) / 256

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  matrixIds[i] = i.toString()
  resolutions[i] = maxResolution / Math.pow(2, i)
}

const parcellaireSource = new WMTS({
  url: "https://data.geopf.fr/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities",
  layer: "CADASTRALPARCELS.PARCELLAIRE_EXPRESS",
  matrixSet: "PM",
  format: "image/png",
  projection: "EPSG:3857",
  matrixSet: "PM",
  tileGrid: new WMTSTileGrid({
    origin: [-20037508, 20037508],
    resolutions: resolutions,
    matrixIds: matrixIds,
  }),
  style: "normal",
})

const parcellaireWMTSCouche = new TileLayer({
  title: "parcellaire",
  source: parcellaireSource,
})

map.addLayer(parcellaireWMTSCouche)
```

I get the error :

> A resource is blocked by OpaqueResponseBlocking, please check browser console for details.

many times, I guess for each tile, and nothing is displayed.

In the console here is what I see :
[image]

I can't find why it is blocked.

Comment: Use only `url: "https://data.geopf.fr/wmts",` for the source to request tiles (similar to this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts-ign.html)  You only need `&request=GetCapabilities` if you set up layers in the same way as `wmts3413` in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection.html